# Where are the images/videos in the "recently deleted" folder of the gallery app actually stored in internal storage?

Tags: android, path, storage

Like every other image in gallery is stored in a path like an image in camera folder is "storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/img.jpg"

So where does the images/videos in my "recently deleted" folder be stored in internal storage. Is there a way to get the path.

Comment: Who deleted those files? Which app? And where do you see that recently deleted folder?

Comment: If my app deletes a file then it is deleted.

Comment: In the official gallery or photos app of most android devices

Answer (score -1):

> > "storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/img.jpg"

Have a look at

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/.trashed-1708200305-img.jpg
```

Comment: But i haven't found any of the deleted photos in that folder in my device (I checked on 3 devices running android 10,11 & 13) and yes I enabled show hidden files too but haven't found trash items there

Comment: Think that it depends on the used device. Sorry.